# Total days in last year

Tags: c#

I have label1 label2 and button1 where i push button1, label1 text will changed based on last month total days (lets say '31' days) and label2 text will changed base on last years total days (lets say '365' days)

I only know how to coding last month total days which i use **DateTime.DaysInMonth** but there's no method for **DateTime.DaysInYear** isn't it

here's my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Last Month
    string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
    int months = Int32.Parse(month);
    int previousmonths = months - 1;

    //Month in this Year
    string year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
    int years = Int32.Parse(year);
    int daysmonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(years, previousmonths);
    MessageBox.Show(daysmonth.ToString());

    //Last Year
    string year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
    int years = Int32.Parse(year);
    int lastyears = years - 1;
    int daysyear = DateTime.DaysInYear(lastyears);
    MessageBox.Show(daysyear.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The code you have looks very strange assuming you've looked up how it an be done -  https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+days+in+year...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I remember, there are always 365 (366 days) in year (leap year).

You can simply use `DateTime.IsLeapYear`:

```
public static int DaysInYear(int year)
{
    return DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
}
```

However, looking at your code, I think that you overcomplicate it.
You don't need to format your DateTime as string and then parse it again.

Your code can be rewritten in a cleaner way:

```
// Days in previous Month
var monthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
int daysMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(monthAgo.Year, monthAgo.Month); 
MessageBox.Show(daysMonth.ToString());

// Days in Previous Year
int daysYear = DaysInYear(DateTime.Now.Year - 1); // see my function above
MessageBox.Show(daysYear.ToString());
```

Comment: Consider using NodaTime if you need more accuracy

Comment: NodaTime is indeed awesome, but not sure if it's more accurate at counting days :)

Answer (score 5):

There are some more elegant ways to get to last month and last year.

```
var lastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month;
var lastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year;
```

From there, getting the number of days in the year is simple like Yeldar pointed out:

```
var daysInLastYear = DateTime.IsLeapYear(yelastYear) ? 366 : 365;
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can have this solution that help to count two day's count

```
class sample2
{
    internal static void Test()
    {
        var sampleTarget = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1);

        var dayInYearForTarget = DayInYear(sampleTarget);
        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0} => {1}", sampleTarget, dayInYearForTarget);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static double DayInYear(DateTime target)
    {
        var date = target.Date;
        var year = date.Year;

        return date.Subtract(new DateTime(year, 1, 1)).TotalDays + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getdaysinyear?view=netcore-3.1) class.
Example of using:

```
        var year = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-1).Year;
        var daysInLastYear = Calendar.ReadOnly(new GregorianCalendar()).GetDaysInYear(year);
```